# How to handle serial asynchronous tasks in multiple node.js servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to run an asynchronous task (an script file) identified by name in serial from different Node.js servers using [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) on the same machine.

For example, I have a task named "SUM" which sums two numbers and return the result in 100 ms:

- From server C run SUM with (1, 4) at 12:35:15.008
- From server A run SUM with (2, 5) at 12:35:15.025
- From server A run SUM with (7, 2) at 12:35:15.092
- Server C by SUM receives (5) at 12:35:15.108
- Server A by SUM receives (7) at 12:35:15.208
- Server A by SUM receives (9) at 12:35:15.308

The task SUM was ran in serial from different servers.

Let's say the API of the utility is a function to run the task, which is an script, as a web-worker, maybe.

```
const serialAsyncMultiCore = require('xxx');

// Parameters: name of the task and script path
const sum = serialAsyncMultiCore.register('SUM', './sum.js');

sum.run([1, 4], function (err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(res);  // 5
});
```

I suppose I have to use something to maintain the state of the processes (such as a database, maybe in-memory like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or a file), something to register the tasks and listen for the result ([socket.io](http://socket.io)?), and something like a server to listen to new tasks and notify of results.

How can I accomplish this? Is there a library?

Comment: show relevant existing code in the question if you want help with your code

Comment: @JaromandaX I added an hypothetical example of the possible API of the utility

Comment: why node.js? it was not built for that.. try a different technology which actually supports multi-threading from the start.

Comment: I lose the good things about node.js if I chose a different technology. I need it in node.js